# the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Failed to load resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am facing issue in accessing public folder of laravel.

I am on ubuntu 17.10.

I am trying to run the app on localhost.

I am accessing like this:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/img/person.jpg')}}"/>
```

Also when checking the its source , its path is shown correct :

`<img src="http://localhost:8000/public/assets/img/person.jpg"/>`

It may seem duplicate but I've tried most of the solutions present on net.

Comment: Remove the word public just start to assets folder

Comment: Did you symlink your public directory? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: that's the issue with so , people downvote if they don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong directory
 Instead of

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/img/person.jpg')}}"/>
```

Use this instead

```
   <img src="{{asset('assets/img/person.jpg')}}"/>
```

Considering the assets folder is existing in public folder.

I hope this will solve you :)

Just in case file had cached on your browser try to add query string on your file by doing this so browser will treat it as a new file

Comment: Remove the URL call just use asset( ill update my answerr

Comment: What laravel u are using ?

Comment: @still no luck ... I am using v5.2

Comment: Neither check the permission of the assets folder nor the specific file you are trying to point. :)

Comment: Try different file with the same code . Or if its cached u can add version control on it

Comment: its the case with every file ...css,js,jpg

Comment: What webserver u are using. It is apacher or nginx ? And php version?

Comment: apache2 and php7.1

Comment: Php to restart ung serv

Comment: restart apache2 server?

Comment: I mean yes. Restart ung apache. And artisan serve as well

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use `Storage::get()` to retrive the file url. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem#retrieving-files)

anyway, you don't need that **public** in the path:

Switch

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('public/assets/img/person.jpg')}}"/>
```

to

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('assets/img/person.jpg')}}"/>
```

Comment: Do you have an asset directory in your public folder?